# RandomVariate without zero

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, scripting

I want to get 10 random numbers drawn from a Poisson distribution with mean 1. But I do not want to include 0 in this. When I do

```
RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1], 10]
```

it gives me 10 random numbers with zero. Is there any workaround?

Comment: `DeleteCases[..., 0]`? Note that excluding numbers from a random distribution via any mechanism will almost certainly change the mean. You could also just add 1 to the list returned by `RandomVariate`, which will obviously increase the mean by 1 (but won't alter the variance).

Comment: Maybe `RandomVariate[
 CensoredDistribution[{1, \[Infinity]}, PoissonDistribution[1]], 10]` ?

Comment: or truncate .. `RandomVariate[ TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, PoissonDistribution[1]], 10]`

Comment: incidentally... Truncate appears to be equivalent to simply deleting zeros.  "censoring" weights the result to give relatively more `1`'s.